# `ls -G` output format changes with less column spacing

Tags: terminal

I want to see coloured output of the `ls` command and so I added

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

to `.bashrc` file but now the spacing between columns in the output of the `ls` command changes. How do I maintain the same spacing between columns as the `ls` command without `-G` option?

[image]

Comment: You're right...I was multi-tasking and didn't read it through.  What if you tried ls -WG for the non-printable characters.

Comment: I just removed my aliases and tried `ls` and `ls -G` my columns line up perfectly.   Do you have anything else in your `.bash_profile` (or anywhere else) that will modify the behavior of `ls`?

Comment: @Allan I checked `.bashrc, bash_profile, .profile` and there's nothing which could possibly alter the behaviour of `ls` command.

Comment: I have the same behavior and at last managed to find some reference about it. I currently have `ls` aliased to `ls -G`, but that's it.